PywinAuto print_control_identifiers not identifying a control *updated with code*
When trying to automate the loading of an extension for work, I am trying to use Pywinauto. I found a great YT but it is using Notepad not Firefox. So there will be some changes and I am fine with trying to sort that out.
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application(backend='uia').start('firefox.exe').connect(title= 'Mozilla Firefox', timeout=100)
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(title= 'Mozilla Firefox', timeout=100)

# app.MozillaFirefox.print_control_identifiers()

searchBar=app.MozillaFirefox.child_window(title="Search or enter address", auto_id="urlbar-input", control_type="Edit").wrapper_object()
searchBar.type_keys('about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox')
searchBar.click_input()

app.MozillaFirefox.print_control_identifiers()

And get a list. But that list does not have the button that is titled: Load Temporary Add-ons.
I have copied the list out to N++ to search easier for Load or temp but nothing is found.
Where did I go wrong? Any pointers are appreciated.

First you need to choose the right backend: Application(backend="uia") which is mentioned here: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

My apologies as that is the backend I am using. Here is the code I am using:app = Application(backend='uia').start('firefox.exe').connect(title= 'Mozilla Firefox', timeout=100)
